# Filter nested entities

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using vb.net with Entity framework.

I have this situation :

I have 2 tables related to each other : Table1(Id,vl1,vl2,vl3,vl4 ) and Table2 (id,nm1,nm2,nm3,Table1ID)

I'm creating a query step by step like this :

Query=From t in context.Table1 select t

If condition1 then query=query.Where(Function(t2) t2.vl1>10)

If condition2 then Query=query.Where(Function(t2) t2.vl2<4)

.....

Now , if Condition3 is true I want to select all records from Table1 where vl3=0 and I want to filter the nested table Table2 where nm1="x".

If condition3 then query=query.where(Function(t2) t2.vl3=0) ???????????????

How can I filter the table2 in my query ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Table1 should be a field that contient the Childs Entities from Table2.

Suppose that the field is called Table2, You can do this:

```
 dim q = query.where(Function(t2) t2.vl3=0)
              .Select(Function(row) New With {.T1Row = row,
                                              .ChildsT2Filtered = T1Row.Table2.Where(Function(xRow) xRow.nm1="x")}
```

Comment: Ok , but I want to keep the construct of entity , and I don't want an anonymos object with "New"